# Intellij terminal is messed up

Tags: intellij-idea

Yesterday, I started having some problems with my intellij terminal. I think it was after I installed ConEmu my terminal looked strange.

This is what my terminal looks like in intellij now:

> ←[m←[32m←]9;8;"USERNAME"←\@←]9;8;"COMPUTERNAME"←\ ←[92mC:\Dev\Project\

Has anyone had a similar issue, if so, how did you fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't really fix the issue, but I replaced the normal terminal (cmd) in intellij with cmder.

The terminal setting (CTRL + ALT + S) -> terminal

cmd.exe /k ""%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\init.bat""

Comment: And that also opens the cmder in current project folder, good solution.